# Creating an array in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, arrays, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to pick a random item from an array while performing an update in Oracle. What is the easiest way to achieve this?

I want something like this:

DECALRE ARRAY items = ('item1', 'item2', 'item3')

update table set field = items(TRUNCT(DBMS_RANDOM.value(1,3)))

that way a random value from the list is inserted in the field for each record that is being updated.

Comment: Why do you need an array to do this? Why not just update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a fixed size array, you can use a VARRAY in PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE strArray IS VARRAY(3) of VARCHAR2(10);
    v_myarray strArray;
BEGIN
    v_myarray := strArray('item1', 'item2', 'item3');
    update table
    set field = v_myarray(DBMS_RANDOM.value(1,3));   
END;
/
```